# In shader nodes, how can I get the position and rotation of a camera?

Tags: node-editor, objects, camera

I'm using shader nodes, and I'm attempting to get the orientation vector of the camera for toon shading. I've tried camera data node but the result wasn't what I wanted. Do I need to script something for it? Or are there other solutions? Thanks.

Comment: what nodes? shader nodes? geometry nodes?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but I mean the shader nodes

Comment: Texture coordinate - Normal put in Vector Transform (type normal, from object to camera space)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to return the World Space camera location and the direction it's pointing, in a shader-tree, these clusters should do it:

[image]